# How to clear binding, defined in application-level style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an appication-level style for `ComboBoxItem`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" x:Key="DefaultComboBoxItemStyle">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxItemStyle}" />
```

This style is suitable for me in 99% cases. But, there's 1%, when bound objects haven't `IsSelected` property. I want to override this binding (in particular, clear it at all).

I thought, that this will be possible this way:

```
        <!-- somewhere in application code -->
        <ComboBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxItemStyle}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
```

But it doesn't work, binding errors still present.
Is there any way to achieve what I want in XAML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `ItemContainerStyle` for the non-default ComboBoxes, you may create a *different* default style in their local `Resources`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        ...
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ComboBox ...>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <!-- local default style based on "global" default style -->
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it a little later. But then there's a following question - why style from resources should replace application style, but directly set style doesn't do this?

Comment: Apparently the default Style is always applied, regardless of the fact that another Style is set later, when the ComboBox has created a new ComboBoxItem instance and applies its `ItemContainerStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [fallback value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) to false in your application - level style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" x:Key="DefaultComboBoxItemStyle">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=False}" />
    <!-- ... -->
</Style>
```

**EDIT:**
Try FallBack value combined with [Priority Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.prioritybinding.aspx) to avoid binding errors.

modified application style will look like

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" x:Key="DefaultComboBoxItemStyle">
    <!-- ... -->
    <Setter Property="IsSelected">
        <Setter.Value>
            <PriorityBinding FallbackValue="False">
                <Binding Path="IsSelected" Mode="TwoWay" />
            </PriorityBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Well, I want binding engine even don't try to operate with binding.